# Laravel session vs sanctum api token vs jwt for a hybrid SPA and mobile app

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, jwt, session-cookies

The Laravel sanctum documentation suggests using the stateful way to authenticte your own SPA and use the API tokens for other purposes. To my knowledge, JWT and Bearer tokens are both more performant than Cookie/Session because it doesn't store session files or records or whatever on the server side and stateless authentication is one of the principles of REST apis due to the flexibility it offers. And as far as i know you can achieve the same level of security as the session mechanism with Http-Only cookies and CSRF tokens. My goal is to make an API that will be consumed by my own SPA (built wiht react) and also by my own mobile app (built with react native). I'm planning to do the authentication with bearer tokens for both web and mobile (bearer instead of jwt because i'll store it in the database to be able to logout a user). I want to know why does the Laravel documentation suggest to use stateful authentication for the SPA and what are the advantages ? Isn't the bearer token method just better and easier to implement in my situtation ?

I built my authentication system using the Laravel sanctum way, stateful for the web and stateless for the mobile. Making everything stateless sounds easier to implement and more flexible.